# Values are sent as null when using js prompt

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to save the entered value of the database. However, values are sent as null.
I'm glad if I encode additional help.

HomeConteller.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public void GaleriOlustur(string Adi)
{
    GaleriTanim As = new GaleriTanim() { Adi = Adi };
    db.GaleriTanims.Add(As);
    db.SaveChanges();
    islemler islem = new islemler { islemler1 = "Galeri Oluşturuldu", kayitTarihi = DateTime.Now };
    db.islemlers.Add(islem);
    db.SaveChanges();
    RedirectToAction("GaleriYonet", "Home");

}
```

GaleriYonet.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GaleriOlustur", "Home",FormMethod.Post,new {Adi="Adi"}))
{
    <input type="submit" onclick="GaleriOlustur()" name="Adi" value="Galeri Oluştur"/>
}
```

GaleriYonet.cshtml "Javascript"

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function GaleriOlustur() {
    var Adi = prompt("Galeri İsmi Giriniz");
    if (Adi != null) {
        return Adi;
    } else {
        alert("Bir İsim Girmelisiniz.");
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Which value is sent as null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client side function should either return `true` or `false`. Not the value user entered to the prompt.

I also suggest you keep an input variable value (hidden type) in your form with name matching to your action method parameter name. In your javascript method, when user enter a vliad value, you can update this form control value to that.

Also, you need to do `return GaleriOlustur()` on the `onclick` event

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GaleriOlustur", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { Adi = "Adi" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="Adi" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="return GaleriOlustur()" value="Galeri Oluştur" />
}
```

and in js method, set the input field value to the value user entered.

```
function GaleriOlustur() {
        var adi = prompt("Galeri İsmi Giriniz");
        if (adi !=="") {
            $("input[name='Adi']").val(adi);
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Bir İsim Girmelisiniz.");
            return false;
        }
};
```